# Is every quasi-finite field algebraically closed?

Tags: field-theory, model-theory

It is known that Ax axiomatized the pseudofinite field F as follows: F is quasifinite [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-finite_field] and F is PAC [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_algebraically_closed_field].

I read Zilber's article about how AСF(algebraically closed field ) is pseudofinite in Zariski language. It is also not difficult to notice that the equation $\exists x (x^2+1=0)$ has a solution in a finite field.

I think that after all, an algebraically closed field is pseudofinite.

It is clear that any PAC is AСF. A natural question arises: is any quasi-finite field an ACF?

I found one good problem, from the book [Serre, Jean-Pierre (1979), Local Fields, Graduate Texts in Mathematics, vol. 67, translated by Greenberg, Marvin Jay, Springer-Verlag, ISBN 0-387-90424-7, MR 0554237, Zbl 0423.12016], page 192, exersize 3d:

"Deduce that every ACF $\Omega$ admits a quasi-finite subfield E having $\Omega$ as its algebraic closure."

Comment: "I read Zilber's article about how AСF(algebraically closed field ) is pseudofinite in Zariski language." Which article is that? What is the Zariski language?

Comment: 5.2 Proposition. https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/zilber/inf-to-finite.pdf

Comment: The statement there is that every algebraically closed field is *approximable* by finite fields. "Approximable by finite fields" and "pseudofinite" are not the same. The definition of "approximable" is given at the beginning of Section 3.2 on p.10.

Answer (score 3):

"I think that after all, an algebraically closed field is pseudofinite."

Certainly not. Let $\varphi$ be the sentence asserting that the definable function $x\mapsto x^2$ is surjective but not injective: $(\forall y\, \exists x\, x^2 = y)\land (\exists z\exists w\, (z\neq w\land z^2 = w^2))$. The sentence $\varphi$ is true in every algebraically closed field of characteristic $\neq 2$, but it has no finite model, because in a finite structure $M$, every surjective fuction $M\to M$ is injective.

"It is clear that any PAC is AСF."

No, the implication goes the other way. Algebraically closed fields are PAC, but there are PAC fields which are not algebraically closed.

"A natural question arises: is any quasi-finite field an ACF?"

No. In fact, the negative answer is immediate from the definition of quasi-finite. A field $K$ is quasi-finite if its absolute Galois group is isomorphic to $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$, the profinite completion of the integers. But the absolute Galois group of an algebraically closed field is the trivial group. More concretely, a quasi-finite field has a unique extension of degree $n$ for all $n\geq 1$, but an algebraically closed field has no finite extensions of degree greater than $1$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Even an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0 is not pseudofinite?  I read the proof that you cited above from Garcia  https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~pmtdg/NotesIPM.pdf, and Pillay and friends...

Comment: There is the Ax-Grothendieck theorem: any injective mapping $f : \overline{F}^n \to \overline{F}^n$ is surjective. $\overline{F}$ is an algebraically closed field. https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/03/07/infinite-fields-finite-fields-and-the-ax-grothendieck-theorem/#more-1869  Please explain what a definable map is?

Comment: @MarkhabatovNurlan Yes, even characteristic $0$! I gave you two ways to see this in my answer: (1) by thinking about the squaring map, (2) every pseudofinite field is quasi-finite, and hence not algebraically closed.

Comment: The Ax-Grothendieck theorem says that any injective *polynomial* mapping $K^n\to K^n$ is surjective when $K$ is algebraically closed. Note that the squaring map $x\to x^2$ shows that the converse is not true: it's a polynomial map which is surjective but not injective.

Comment: "Definable map" is a standard term defined in any textbook on model theory. It's a function $f\colon M^n\to M^m$ whose graph is defined by a formula. That is, there is a formula $\varphi(x,y)$ so that $M\models \varphi(a,b)$ iff $f(a)=b$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I became more or less clear.